# addeventlistener in javascript breaks when I replace jQuery with vanilla javascript to copy a html template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jinja2

I am trying to get rid of jQuery from my code and for some reason, this jQuery works and my event listener does not break:

```
$("#modal-body").html(post_template);
```

but when I convert to pure vanilla JavaScript I replace the above with this, but it causes my event listener not to fire:

```
document.getElementById('modal-body').innerHTML=post_template.outerHTML
```

The html gets injected as I want, but it does not load my event listener that is found below the above code:

```
post_template.addEventListener('submit', async (e) =>
```

I assume this has something to do with the way the DOM is loaded for jQuery and Javascript elements, but I do not know how to fix it.

Here is the full function I am trying to rid of jQuery. I commented out the piece that makes it work with jQuery.

```
function build_post_modal() {
    post_template=document.getElementById('post_template')

    document.getElementById('modal-title').innerHTML='Post'

    //This line breaks my event listener and is pure Javascript
    document.getElementById('modal-body').innerHTML=post_template.outerHTML
    //This line makes the event listener work, but it uses jQuery
    $("#modal-body").html(post_template);

    footer="<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-secondary\" data-bs-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>"
    document.getElementById('modal-footer').innerHTML=footer
    //Push template back to DOM on close
    $('#siteModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#post_modal").html(post_template);
        //TODO get typed context to push back to main window
    })

    const fields = {
        csrf_token: {
            input: document.getElementById('csrf_token'),
            error: document.getElementById('csrf_token-error')
        },
        body: {
            input: document.getElementById('body'),
            error: document.getElementById('body-error')
        }
    }
    //This code breaks when I use the pure javascript method for making the modal-body
    post_template.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const response = await fetch('/_submit_post', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                csrf_token: fields.csrf_token.input.value,
                body: fields.body.input.value
            })
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            $('#siteModal').modal('hide')
            jFlash(await response.text())
        } else {
            const errors = await response.json();
            Object.keys(errors).forEach((key) => {
               fields[key].input.classList.add('is-invalid');
               fields[key].error.innerHTML = errors[key][0];
            });
        }
    });

};
```

This is the jinja html that I am trying to pull the template from to style a modal.

```
<a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#siteModal" onclick="build_post_modal()">
    <div class="post d-flex align-items-center">
        <img src="{{ current_user.avatar(50) }}" width="50" class="rounded-circle mr-2">
        <input class="form-control" id="post_body" placeholder="Make a post..." type="text" value="">
    </div>
</a>
<div id="post_modal" style="display: none;">
    <form id="post_template" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div class="text-danger my-2" id="csrf_token-error"></div>
        <div class="post d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ current_user.avatar(50) }}" width="50" class="rounded-circle mr-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.body.label }}
                {{ form.body(class='form-control', placeholder='Make a post...') }}
                <div id="body-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is part of base.html that holds the site modal

```
        <!-- Site Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="siteModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 id="modal-title" class="modal-title"></h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body"></div>
              <div id="modal-footer" class="modal-footer"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `but it breaks a function below that is called by` is not a really helpful descript. What breaks? Is the event handler not called?  Does it fail at a particular line? And if so how does it fail?

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual HTML for the modal? Where are the `modal-title`, `modal-body`, `modal-footer` elements?

Comment: @t.niese I edited it for clarity. For some reason, the event listener stops working when I convert from jQuery. It doesn't throw any errors so I can't debug it easily.

Comment: @Dauros The modal-title and modal-footer elements are found in a different template where I hold the modal for the site. The Jinja above just styles the modal-body element. I plan on using the same title/body templates site wide, so I only need to style the body for each different modal I show.

Comment: Could you please include a complete example then? Now your function fails to run because of the many `getElementById` calls to non-existing elements.

Comment: @Dauros i added the site modal template that loads with base.html

Comment: @Dauros I just noticed when I click the button to open the modal that the id=post_template element disappears from where it sits when I use the jQuery function, but when I use the javascript function it stays. I think jQuery is ripping that element out and putting it into my modal where needed, but the javascript is not doing this. I'm unsure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the HTML of an element like this, the attached event listeners do not survive the operation. This is the reason `post_template.addEventListener('submit', ...)` part does not execute on the submit event. jQuery does some magic to copy the events as well. The simplest solution in vanilla JS is a little bit old, but does the trick: use the `onsubmit` attribute at the form.

```
<div id="post_modal" style="display: none;">
  <form id="post_template" method="POST" onsubmit="post_form(event)">
     <!-- Rest of the form... -->
  </form>
</div>
```

And the refactored submitting part of your `build_post_modal()` function:

```
async function post_form(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  const fields = {
    csrf_token: {
      input: document.getElementById('csrf_token'),
      error: document.getElementById('csrf_token-error')
    },
    body: {
      input: document.getElementById('body'),
      error: document.getElementById('body-error')
    }
  }

  // Rest of the fetch() logic...
}
</script>
```

You still need to convert some jQuery code to vanilla, just remember to inline the event listeners.